# DatabaseHelper cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

i am doing this..

private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

error:DatabaseHelper cannot be resolved to a type

i am new to android development and getting this error and after importing the  SQLitOpenHelper this error is there....please help me out...?

Comment: http://hackaday.com/2010/07/21/android-development-101-part-3introduction-to-databases/ use this link as a refrence you might get the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to fix your error:

`mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());`

Comment: please refer this link it might help you out ...http://hackaday.com/2010/07/21/android-development-101-part-3introduction-to-databases/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try ActiveRecords for Android, its a painless and very easy to implement library. You can also add your functionality in that library as I did. You can download library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-active-record/)

Comment: you can read all from [here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-activerecord-activerecord-android-style/)